# Why can I not infer an interface from a constrained generic collection?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

I have a piece of code that works like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ICacheMember> Flubvert( IEnumerable<ICacheMember> members ) 
   {
        // do some stuff to members
        return members;
   }
```

However I am confused as to why I can't do this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteFlubversion<T>( IEnumerable<T> memberList ) where T: class,ICacheMember 
{
      return Flubvert( memberList );
}
```

Surely the constraint on the generic should guarantee that `memberList`is an IEnumerable of the `ICacheMember`type? Do I really need to convert a collection of existing ( but implicit ) `ICacheMember` objects into *explicit*  `ICacheMember` objects and then convert them back afterwards? I can understand that I might need to convert them back given the method signature of `Flubvert` but I don't see why I should have to convert them in the method call. This is what I am doing in the working code but it seems completely out of keeping with the generally elegant behaviour of generics so I think I must be misunderstanding something about how this is supposed to operate.

Comment: This is a question about covariance and contravariance.  Don't worry, Jon Skeet will be here soon to explain.

Comment: Why are you adding one level of indirection? Are you composing? Bridge?

Comment: Every class that implements `ICacheMember` is an `ICacheMember` but, not every implemention of `ICacheMember` is from some class that implements it.

Comment: @dariogriffo I don't have time to play cards, I'm busy trying to understand covariance :p I'm adding indirection because the Flubvertion process ( in my current example a search/filter mechanism built from a custom query system ) is soley interested in the ICacheMember interface, which can be implemented by any type found in the Cache, all of which should be Flubvertable in the same way.

Comment: What does "do some stuff" inside `Flubvert` look like? Can you guarantee that the `members` parameter is never assigned to? Because then you can solve your (edited) problem by a simple cast from `IEnumerable<ICacheMember>` to `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is defined by your generic method.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Basically it triggers a whole lot of tests against the ICacheMember methods exposed by the members of `members` so there is no write-behaviour going on - in fact it's largely side-effects-free, but it does depend entirely on that interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all covariance of `IEnumerable<out T>` (and other generic types) only works when `T` is a reference type, so you need:

```
public IEnumerable<ICacheMember> ExecuteFlubversion<T>(IEnumerable<T> memberList)
    where T: class, ICacheMember  // NOTE 'class'
{
    var flub = Flubvert(memberList);   // can you call with 'memberList'?
    return flub;                       // can you return that type?

    // depending on what 'Flubvert' does, maybe return 'IEnumerable<T>'
    // and say:
    // return (IEnumerable<T>)flub;
}
```

Also note that I changed the return value. The C# compiler cannot guarantee that the returned object from the non-generic `Flubvert` method is anything more specific than `IEnumerable<ICacheMember>`.

Comment: Good point, I have that in my code, so I'll update the question. Doesn't affect the specific behaviour that I am confused by.

Comment: @glenatron Your original code (before edit) gave a compile-time error because covariance in generics only works with reference types. Your new code gives another compile-time error. The call `Flubvert(memberList)` is now good. The problem now lies in the `return` part. As I indicated, the C# compiler cannot know what `IEnumerable<>` the non-generic method returns, only that it is compatible with `IEnumerable<ICacheMember>`. It could infact be a `List<ICacheMember>`, as an example, and that is not a `List<>` of your `T`. Other strange things could be in such a `List<>`.

Comment: Yup, you're absolutely right. As I say in the question, I get that I need an explicit conversion back or a change of the return signature, I'm really interested in why I can't _call_ the method.

Comment: @glenatron You _can_ call the method. I will write your generic method with two code lines to make it clearer. Editing.

Comment: You're right, I can. Great, now I can't see why there was a problem in the first place. It _definitely_ wasn't working earlier, I swear :/

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have:

```
interface ICacheMemberSub : ICacheMember
{
  ...
}
```

And you call your function like this:

```
ExecuteFlubversion<ICacheMemberSub>(cacheMember);
```

This function will try to return an object with type `IEnumerable<ICacheMember>`, and that is not necessarily castable to  `IEnumerable<ICacheMemberSub>`, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

At risk of not directly answering the question, can you change the signature of Flubvert to a generic?  If you make Flubvert generic, the rest of the method code will stay the same and you can still assume that the members will be implementers of ICacheMember.

```
public IEnumerable<T> Flubvert<T>(IEnumerable<T> members)
    where T : class, ICacheMember
{
    // do some stuff to members
    return members;
}


public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteFlubversion<T>(IEnumerable<T> memberList)
    where T : class,ICacheMember
{
    return Flubvert(memberList);
}
```